# How to scan IBeacon for a specific UUID in background even when the Application is killed in Android Oreo or later?

Tags: android, altbeacon

I want to scan IBeacon for a specific UUID in background even when the Application is killed in Android Oreo or later. Is there any method or demo? If used [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html), how to specify a specific UUID?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is generally possible to detect beacons after an app is killed on Android with certain limitations.  The Android Beacon Library has this feature built-in, and details are described [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html).  **Be sure you understand the limitations described in the documentation.**  Detection after killing an app is not instantaneous and generally takes up to 25 minutes on Android 8+ devices, but that is rarely a problem outside of developer testing.  Just don't make a mistake of killing an app, immediately turning on a beacon, then thinking it doesn't work because you don't get a notification right away. You have to wait.

The library [reference application](https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) demonstrates this ability.  That reference searches for any beacon, but it is easily modified to search for only a specific UUID. To do so just change the code below.

From:

```
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
```

To:

```
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6", null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
```

Replacing `2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6` with your ProximityUUID.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer solved my problem.